# Cannot deploy contract in new Remix layout

Tags: solidity, remix

I cannot get a contract to deploy in the new layout but when I go back to the old format it works fine. The deployment parameters are as follows:

[image]

and here is the error that I get:

[image]

However, when I go back to the old format it deploys without any problem.

Does anyone have an idea what is going on?

Thanks!

Comment: What is that hex number used as argument for  the deployment of Platform ? It looks like it's 11 bytes, while the format is 16. I wonder if there's some padding going on, left in old and right in new or the contrary... you can try and use an explicit full 16 bytes value to rule this out.

Comment: @blackscale That is the problem! I padded to the left and it worked. Thank-you! If you answer the question, I will give you credit. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer to my comment seems to indicate that the new UI of Remix now adds some right-padding.

Padding left yourself is a good solution for manual testing. When you get to build a Dapp, be very careful about sanitizing inputs.